# R ggplot2: different color and alpha styling for different geom_point depending on y value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create the earthquake graph with the look based on this reference [Earthquake viz reference](https://datainnovation.org/2019/08/visualizing-16000-aftershocks-from-earthquakes/)

**Data**
The [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-N494FwAiB06sPnqC9n3aEAWx1pRpGv_/view?usp=share_link) is look like this:

```
head(df)
|Date      |Time.UTC|Latitude|Longitude|Depth|Depth.Type|Magnitude.Type|Magnitude|Region.Name                |Last.Update     |Eqid   |X  |color  |
|----------|--------|--------|---------|-----|----------|--------------|---------|---------------------------|----------------|-------|---|-------|
|2023-02-10|06:11:56|-0.13   |123.12   |137  |          | M            |2.5      |SULAWESI, INDONESIA        |2023-02-10 06:20|1221400|   |#C4C4C4|
|2023-02-10|06:00:14|-1.79   |100.42   |27   |          | M            |2.9      |SOUTHERN SUMATRA, INDONESIA|2023-02-10 06:10|1221398|   |#C4C4C4|
|2023-02-10|05:59:27|-1.31   |120.44   |10   |          | M            |2.7      |SULAWESI, INDONESIA        |2023-02-10 06:05|1221396|   |#C4C4C4|
|2023-02-10|05:26:25|-6.14   |104.72   |35   |          | M            |3.9      |SUNDA STRAIT, INDONESIA    |2023-02-10 05:35|1221388|   |#C4C4C4|
|2023-02-10|05:10:06|-8.08   |117.78   |18   |          | M            |2.8      |SUMBAWA REGION, INDONESIA  |2023-02-10 05:15|1221377|   |#C4C4C4|
|2023-02-10|04:55:01|0.99    |98.06    |25   |          | M            |3.3      |NIAS REGION, INDONESIA     |2023-02-10 05:05|1221370|   |#C4C4C4|
```

**Code used**

```
ggplot(df,aes(Date, Magnitude)) +
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(Magnitude > 5),
             alpha = 0.9, size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0,
             color = "#264653")+
  geom_point(aes(color = Magnitude),
             data = df %>% filter(Magnitude <= 5),
             alpha = 1/20, size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0)
```

**Output**
[image: result1]

**Expectation**
I'm expecting that the `geom_points` for the data where its magnitude is below or equal to 5 to have grey color and use transparency gradient (higher magnitude, higher alpha, vice versa).
While `geom_points` for the data above 5, only plain solid color

**Other test**
I tried to add

```
scale_color_gradient(low=alpha("#BFBFBF",0),high = alpha("#6B6B6B",0.9))
```

But the result have no transparency gradient as expected
[image: result2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option.
The `ggplot` has one `geom_point` with data filtered to `Magnitude > 5`. This has `color = Magnitude` in `aes`.  This gives the possibility to style the color of those points with `scale_color_gradiant2` as done below.
The other data are also filtered ( `Magnitude <= 5`) and `Magnitude` is renamed to `mag`. This gives the possibility to style those points independently from the other. You can use `geom_point`. But this may lead to some overplotting and the impression that the `alpha` is not applied.
I have used `geom_jitter` to avoid overplotting.

I have also taken the freedom to use different sizes for the different subsets and some color.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data |> filter(Magnitude > 5), aes(
    Date, Magnitude,
    color = Magnitude 
  ), size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  # here you can also use geom_point
  geom_jitter(data = data |>
    filter(Magnitude <= 5) |> rename(mag = Magnitude), aes(
    Date, mag,
    alpha = mag
  ), color = "grey", size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(
    low = "green",
    mid = "orange",
    high = "red",
    midpoint = 6,
    guide = "none",
    aesthetics = "colour"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can fake your alpha with segments. This gives you much better control than using scale_alpha (in my opinion).

I have adjusted the look to come a bit closer to your linked example graph. The trick is to assign alpha values to your Magnitude values. In the data frame which does that, you can influence where your alpha will have which value.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "day"), 10),
                 Magnitude = runif(3650, max = 5))
## generate your alpha segments
df_seg <- data.frame(y = seq(min(df$Magnitude), max(df$Magnitude), len = 1000), 
                     alpha = seq(1, 0.3, len = 1000))

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Magnitude)) +
  ## use alpha as aesthetic
  ## color for the same look as in your linked example graph
  geom_point(aes(color = Magnitude),
    size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = df_seg, aes(
      y = y, yend = y,
      x = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
      xend = as.Date("2021-12-31"),
      alpha = alpha
    ),
    ## you need to play around with the line width a bit
    linewidth = .2,
    color = "white", 
    ## to remove the alpha legend
    show.legend = F
  ) +

  ## add some random divergent colors
  scale_color_gradientn(values = c(0, .4, 1), colors = c("darkgreen", "darkgreen", "red")) +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = F)
```

[image]

I was saying I find it easier to add segments to fake an alpha. As user AllanCameron rightly pointed out, this is arguable. Adding the alpha directly to the colors in `scale_color_gradientn` will also give a nice visual and is indeed much shorter.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Magnitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Magnitude),
             size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0
  ) +
  scale_color_gradientn(values = c(0, .4, 1), 
                        colors =c(alpha("darkgreen", 0.1), alpha("darkgreen", 0.5), "red")) +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = F)
```

[image]

Comment: While this is quite different with what I expected, this gives me a new point of view. Thanks!

Comment: This is closer to the original graphic and looks great IMHO. I wonder if the segments _are_ easier than just setting alpha via `scale_alpha_continuous` or even using `c(alpha("darkgreen", 0.1), alpha("darkgreen", 0.5), "red")` for your colors?

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks! That's actually a fair point. I think I was overthinking :) Let me add this

Comment: Thanks for that @tjebo - looks great. And fixes the legend too.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the transparency gradient by changing the low and high arguments in `scale_alpha()`. To make the lower magnitude earthquakes have a lighter tone, you can increase the low value, for example:

```
ggplot(df,aes(Date, Magnitude)) +
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(Magnitude > 5),
             alpha = 0.9, size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0,
             color = "#264653")+
  geom_point(aes(color = Magnitude),
             data = df %>% filter(Magnitude <= 5),
             alpha = 0.5, size = 1.7, shape = 16, stroke = 0) +
  scale_alpha(limits = c(0, 5), range = c(0.1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this one did not satisfy my expectation yet as it is similar to the 1st result. Once again, my expectation is to have grey dots for the one below <5 `magnitude` and also alpha gradient (the less magnitude, the more transparent/the less alpha)